# Removing an object instance from a list in python

Tags: python, list, object, python-2.7, del

I have this elevator assignment and I'm stuck in 1 place. I have a building object with a list of customers in it. I'm trying a method for a customer to enter an elevator - customer is appended to elevator list but cant fin a way to remove that customer from building list : tried with `del` and `list.remove(item)` but no joy. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
class building(object):  
    def __init__(self, floors = 0, customerNo = 0,):
        self.floors = 0
        self.myE = elevator()
        self.customerNo = 0
        self.customersWaiting = []
        self.customersTransported = []

    def initCustomers(self):        
        cnt = 1
        cust = cnt
        while cnt <= myB.customerNo :
            floor = random.randint(0, self.floors - 1)
            destination = random.randint(0, self.floors - 1)
            cust = customer(cnt, floor , destination )
            self.customersWaiting.append(cust)
            cnt +=1

class customer(object):
    def __init__(self,cnt, floor = 0, destination = 0):
        self.cnt = cnt
        self.floor = floor
        self.destination = destination

    def enterElevator(self):
        for cust in myB.customersWaiting :
            if myB.myE.lvl == self.floor :
                myB.myE.customersIn.append(self)
                #del cust(self)
                #myB.customersWaiting.remove(self)
            else:
                pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is some of my suggestion:

1) building should have N floor, you can have a buildingFactory to create building with n floors.

```
def createBuilding(self, N):
    return building = Building(N)
class Building:
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.floorWatingList= []
        for f in range(N):
            self.floorWaitingList.append() = []
```

2) use clear() or pop() method to remove customer from list

```
for c in building.floorWaitingList[current]:
      elvator.enter(c)
building.floorWaitingList.clear()
```